# Variable wont get recognized when inside partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables

When I create a partial and render it in a view, the variables inside wont get recognized.

**If I put everything in the view, everything will be ok. But If I use a partial, I get this error:**

```
undefined local variable or method `photo' for #<#<Class:0x0000010981db20>:0x000001089681e8>
```

**I've tried to put @ in front of "photo", but still says:**

```
undefined method `photo_url' for nil:NilClass
```

Is there a way in Rails to achieve this?

**My view**

```
    <% @photos.each do |photo| %>
        <%= render partial: "spot_box" %>
    <% end %>
```

**My partial**

```
    <%= link_to spot_path(photo) do %>
        <%= image_tag photo.photo_url(:thumb), class: "" %>
        <%= photo.title.truncate(30).downcase.capitalize %>
        <%= photo.user.name.truncate(10) %> |  <%= photo.pins.count %> Productos etiquetados
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
<%= render partial: "spot_box", locals: { photo: photo } %>
```

By the way you can do directly:

```
render partial: 'spot_box', collection: @photos, as: :photo
```

instead of looping on your `@photos`

More information on partials [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials)

Answer (score 0):

You can also, if you have a collection you want to render the same partial for, replace this

```
<% @photos.each do |photo| %>
    <%= render partial: "spot_box" %>
<% end %>
```

with

```
<%= render partial: "spot_box", collection: @photos, as: :photo %>
```

the "as" option tells rails what to call each member of the collection inside the partial, which needs to be the same variable name as you use inside the partial.  It defaults to the name of the partial, so if you didn't pass `as: :photo` then each member of the collection would be held in a variable called `spot_box`.

see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html